# Can two GFCI outlet loads be powered by two separate circuits?

Tags: wiring, gfci

My garage outlets and my outdoor outlets are all on the same GFCI circuit.  If outdoor circuit gets wet my garage outlets lose power.

Comment: Sure, they can be split, but not from the same outlet. Did you have a more specific question? If so, please provide more specific information about your circuits.

Comment: Is the circuit protected by a GFCI breaker or outlet?  If an outlet, you could get another GFCI outlet and re-wire the feed in the upstream outlet and feed the next outlet on the line side, rather than the load side, then install the new GFCI outlet in the first "downstream" location.

Comment: Thanks George.  Circuit is protected with GFCI outlet.  That helps!

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible to add a circuit and split where things are fed from. The best option would be to add heavy duty covers or in use covers with proper seals as code requires on outside receptacles in wet locations this keeps the receptacles dry so they won’t be the cause of the trip.
If the garage is attached to the home adding circuits is much easy and less restrictive rules apply than for a detached structure.